# (C) Which characters are affected when writing to a file in a text mode instead of binary mode?

Tags: c, file, text, io, binary

I have encountered this question while I was studying for a test. Given answers were:

a) `'a'`
b) `'\n'`
c) `'012'`
d) `'\0'`

I tried to find the general rule but I failed.

Comment: What is the meaning of each character? [Is any of them special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)?

Comment: `'012'` is not the same as `012`. Are you sure about the precise spelling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `'\n'`, of the listed 4, is certainly affected by writing to a file in a text mode instead of binary mode.

With a *text file*, the *new-line character* `'\n'` is commonly translated to/from `'\n'` (no change), `"\r\n"`, or rarely `\r'`.

`'012'` is a multi-character constant with an implementation defined value, unlikely to be affected by the mode.

The unlisted `'\012'` is a *character constant* employing an *octal escape sequence*. It behaves like `'\n'` when ASCII is the source encoding.

The unlisted `012` is an *octal  constant*.  It behaves like `'\012'`.

Sneaky test if you ask me.

Comment: I am not sure if the OP used quotes to emphasize the answers or if the quotes were actually present in the question. Using `'012'` in a test is pretty bad, just like *what does `strlen("??/??/????")` evaluate to?* and *What is the value of `0x2E+1`?*

Comment: @chqrlie Agree.  That is why I addressed the literal posting as well as similar variations

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ASCII, the octal value `012` is the same as the line-feed (`\n`) character, so b), c) and d) are the correct answers (the line ending will be changed to whatever is appropriate for your system, which may be `\r` or `\r\n`; `fprintf` and `fputs` will stop on a null character; `fwrite` (binary) will not)

If your character set is *not* explicitly stated to be ASCII, then the only assumption you are safe to make is that b) and d), the newline character `\n` and null terminator `\0` will be treated differently in binary mode than text mode.

Comment: Technically, the behavior on `'\0'` is unrelated to text vs binary mode.  It is a feature of `fputs` and `fprintf` to stop on the null byte regardless of the mode the file is opened for.  Similarly, `fread` and `fwrite` will read and write null bytes from and to text streams if instructed to. d) does not seem to be a correct answer to me.

Comment: Note: `fprintf()` can be coaxed to print the null character such as `fprintf(out, "%cABC", 0);` will print 4 characters: `'\0'`, `'A'` , `'B'` , `'C'`.

Comment: "the octal value 012 is the same as the line-feed" in ASCII is true, but `012` is not option B.  That is `'012'`, a multi character constant.  Try `printf("%#x\n", '012');`.  That outputs `0x303132` for me.